# How do I change the active state of my nav?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

How do I change the active state of my nav?  When I click on a nav link it looks like it has set an active state as the background of the `li` changes.  I want the underline to be set when the link has been clicked.  I'm setting this in the css so not sure what I'm doing wrong.

Any ideas?

[Here's a plnkr](https://plnkr.co/edit/SneuJ3N4MqxEDnohdcmu?p=preview)

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put these lines in your CSS file:

```
.nav > li > a:hover, .nav > li > a:focus {
text-decoration: none;
border-bottom: 4px solid #2a3245;
background-color: #eee;
}
```